# Geometric meaning of independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

When I studied the definition of independence during my probability theory classes I've seen something like this:

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

If this is true, then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

But what does it mean in terms of probability measures or even in the simple model of geometrical probability? How can we multiply areas or measures? If we multiply areas in the geometrical probability model, we should have a volume, but not an area of events intersection. How is it work? I need your geometric intuition)

Comment: Consider the ratio of the area of $(A)$ versus the area of the universe and the ratio of the area of $(A \cap B)$ versus the area of $(B)$.  $A$ is independent of $B$, if and only if the two ratios are the same.  Also, $A$ is independent of $B$ if and only if $B$ is independent of $A$.

Comment: What is "the simple model of geometrical probability"?

Comment: @Tobsn the model of probability space constructed by the intuitive meaning of area https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_probability